# How can I split HH:MM:SS into NSArray using componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

Like this `NSString @"2013-09-02 0:00:00 +0800"` I can split it into NSArray using `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` method.

The Array looks like this

```
@["2013-09-02", "0:00:00", "+0800"].
```

But how can I split `NSString @"0:00:00"` into NSArray looks like

`@[@"0", "00", "00"]`
 in Objective-C using `

`componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the hours, minutes and seconds of a date you should probably use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) first and then extract these properties with [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSString *yourString = @"2013-09-02 0:00:00 +0800";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourString];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger hour = components.hour;
NSInteger minute = components.minute;
NSInteger second = components.second;

//Alternative (NSArray can only contain objects - NSNumber vs. NSInteger)
NSArray *yourArray = @[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:components.hour],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInteger:components.minute],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInteger:components.second]];`
```

It might seem like more code but it is the cleaner solution. And remember NSDateFormatter is relatively expensive to create. If you can do it you should create it outside of a loop (it is not thread safe though);

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *originalValue =  @"2013-09-02 0:00:00 +0800";

// First seperated by white space
NSArray *spaceSeperated= [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; // result would be @[@"2013-09-02", @"0:00:00", @"+0800"]

// now for time string seperate that one by :
NSArray *timeSeperated = [[spaceSeperated objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

Now, **timeSeperate** array will contains time value in 3 separate objects: **@[@"0" , @"00" , @"00"]**

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arr = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `componentsSeparatedByString:@":"` method.